# About the exponential bounds for modified Bessel function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Dear colleagues, 
I want to know if there are some results on the bounds of modified Bessel functions $I_\alpha(x)$ and $K_\alpha(x)$? Especially, I need the exponential bounds for them, that is to say if it is possible to get a result like

$|I_\alpha(x)|\leq C exp(b x), x\geq 0$

where $C$ is a constant or a polynomial of $x$, b is a constant, $\alpha$ is a real number. Also the inequality of the same form about $K_\alpha(x)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [The Abramowitz-Stegun Handbook has some asymptotics](http://convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/Reference/AMS55.ASP?Res=150&Page=375) that may help you.


Comment: Maybe this is going the wrong way round, but another possible bound can be obtained by using $I_\nu(z) = (z/2)e^z M(0.5+\nu; 1+2\nu; 2z) / \Gamma(\nu+1)$, where $M$ is Kummer's function. Now, you can invoke Stirling's approximation for $\Gamma$, and one of the many approximations for $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bounds of that form in [this paper](http://www.bepress.com/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1064&context=mdandersonbiostat). See also the first reference at the end of the paper.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think your comments will help me a lot!

Comment: A user named "lonewolf" has pointed out that the link is now dead.